# WPF moving animation and staying there

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

I'm newbie to C# and I'm trying to do a simple application which have elements that move a lot on the screen. After some research I found a code that moved a button. The problem is the button returns to it's original state (although invisible). When I click the button it moves outside the screen (just as I wanted), but when I click it back (it should do the reverse animation) but instead, it just magically appears on the screen again.

I also tried to make it change position after the animation ended, but that didn't work either. Here's my code:

```
    private void ButtonOnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (nextSlideMoving)
            return;
        nextSlideMoving = true;
        KinectTileButton target = (KinectTileButton)sender;
        Vector offset = VisualTreeHelper.GetOffset(target);
        if (nextSlideHidden)
            moveAnimation(target, 0, offset.Y);
        else
            moveAnimation(target, -target.ActualWidth, offset.Y);
    }

    private void moveAnimation(KinectTileButton target, double newX, double newY)
    {
        Vector offset = VisualTreeHelper.GetOffset(target);
        var top = offset.Y;
        var left = offset.X;

        TranslateTransform trans = new TranslateTransform();
        target.RenderTransform = trans;

        DoubleAnimation anim1 = new DoubleAnimation(0, newY - top, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5));
        trans.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.YProperty, anim1);
        DoubleAnimation anim2 = new DoubleAnimation(0, newX - left, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5));
        anim2.Completed += new EventHandler(finishedAnimation);
        trans.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.XProperty, anim2);
    }

    public void finishedAnimation(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        nextSlideMoving = false;
        nextSlideHidden = !nextSlideHidden;
        Console.WriteLine(nextSlideHidden);
        if (nextSlideHidden)
            nextSlide.Margin = new Thickness(-(SystemParameters.VirtualScreenWidth * 0.2), SystemParameters.VirtualScreenHeight * 0.2, SystemParameters.VirtualScreenWidth * 0.8, SystemParameters.VirtualScreenHeight * 0.2); // (LEFT, TOP, RIGHT, BOTTOM)
        else
            nextSlide.Margin = new Thickness(0, SystemParameters.VirtualScreenHeight * 0.2, SystemParameters.VirtualScreenWidth * 0.8, SystemParameters.VirtualScreenHeight * 0.2); // (LEFT, TOP, RIGHT, BOTTOM)
    }
```

Comment: ricardo it is very difficult to write animation using code..so it would be better if you use blend for making animation (storyboards)..

Comment: I'll take a look on how the storyboard work. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be asking for FillBehavior. Take a look at following link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.fillbehavior(v=vs.110).aspx

Also take a look at AutoReverse property:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.autoreverse(v=vs.110).aspx

If those properties doesn't help you any futher I would gladly take a look at your example just please upload it online.

Comment: I'll take a look at them and let you know. I'm used to Java, although it is very similiar to C#, I'm not used to this XAML and not familiar enough on how to work with interface layouts.

Comment: You tagged c# in your question. However try it out and if you still have issues let me know :)

Comment: My question about C#, but what I was saying is that I'm not used to it, has I'm just experienced in Java (the language that I use since a long time ago)